# Is it possible to add add elements to an array using IntStream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was using this macro in cpp

```
forn(i,3) cin>>arr[n]; //assume arr initialised earlier
```

> So I was tried to achieve this in Java using lambda and IntStream

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  IntStream.range(0, 5).map(i->arr[i]).forEach(e->e=sc.nextInt());
```

But I know that stream doesn't manipulate the underlying data structure. so Can I achieve this using streams or I've to create my own functional interface to do so? thank you

Comment: Streams aren't meant to replace every other kind of iteration, here a for loop will be as easy to use. Looks like you want `for (int i=0; i<5; i++) { arr[i]=sc.nextInt(); }`

Comment: Streams are used to apply  a set of operations on a collection (stream) of data, they are not necessarily a replacement for flow structures such as a for-loop.

Comment: Aside: How did `forn(i,3)` translate to `IntStream.range(0, 5)`? (The bounds definitely differ if I am not mistaken.)

Comment: Actually I was trying a different way than the traditional for loop. Consider the macro given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> arr[i] = sc.nextInt());
```

But also note that this is not a great use case for Streams. A simple loop would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for the use of `toArray` with `IntStream` while you map the integer provided as an input:

```
int arr[] = IntStream.range(0, 5).map(i -> sc.nextInt()).toArray()
```

Comment: Your approch is good but Actually I was thinking of adding values to underlying array not to create a dummy one .